# A segment of code I made in Python 3 does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following segment of code does not work properly.

#### Error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

#### Code:

```
name = input()
age = input()
if name == ('alice'):
    print('hello alice')
elif age < 12:
    print('you arent alice, kiddo')
elif age > 2000:
    print ('now thats just crazy you cant be that old')
elif age > 70:
    print ('are too old to be alice')
```

PS: I'm new to programming

Comment: be logical: you're using the same statement to input `name` (a string) and `age`. What type do you think that `age` is? (hint: the error message kills the fun by telling the exact problem)

Comment: note: it wouldn't work in python 2 either, and it won't work in python 45...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly cast the result of the second line, as in

```
age = int(input())
```

Comment: please refrain from answering such bad questions... my comments are better than your answer, and posted earlier too.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the SO community. I would comment on a question like this, if I could.

Comment: thanks but i still don't understand why this works and my line of code doesn't work.... i should note im new to coding

Comment: It's because the `input()` function returns a string and not an integer. For example, if the user gives 13, then the age variable would have the value `'13'` and not `13`. What you are doing is comparing a string to an integer, which is not allowed.

Comment: does that mean that **input** always treats its input as string and needs to be told that i want it to be integral or float and such?

Comment: It doesn't treat the input as a string. It just returns a string. Your program should be told that the string, that gets returned, needs to be converted to an integer, before it is stored into the `age` variable.